# Can't login to namecheap with python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am trying to login to namecheap.com with selenium but can't select the login forms. I got this error when selecting elements:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

But I can see I selected ok the xpath.
Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

cookie_file_path = 'cookie.txt'

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] =("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36")

# driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap,service_args=['--ssl-protocol=any','--ignore-ssl-errors=true','--cookies-file={}'.format(cookie_file_path)])
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
username='test'
password='test123'

driver.get('https://www.namecheap.com/myaccount/login.aspx')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='LoginUserName']").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="LoginPassword"]').send_keys(password)
loginButtonXpath = "//input[@type='submit']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath).click()
driver.save_screenshot('testing.png')
```

and here is the HTML:

```
                    <div class="sign-in-form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="text" name="LoginUserName" title="Username" placeholder="Username" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" class="input removespecialchars handlereturn" maxlength="20" />
                        <input type="password" name="LoginPassword" title="Password" placeholder="Password" class="input handlereturn" maxlength="100" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_LoginPassword" />
                        <a href="https://www.namecheap.com/myaccount/login.aspx" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_base_content_web_base_content_topNavLoginLink" class="head-loginb ncRedirectButton btn sign-in-btn btn-block" rel="nofollow">Sign In</a>
                        <a href="https://ap.www.namecheap.com/ResetPassword" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_base_content_web_base_content_passwordRemiderLink" title="Password Reminder">Forgot your password?</a>
                    </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="hidewhenloggedin"><a href="/myaccount/signup.aspx">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li class="expandable signed-in hidewhennotloggedin  user-menu">
```

Can you help me out?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your xPath locators (for login/username) are the reason of failure.

Try using following CSS locators..

```
Username
css=div.group > input[name="LoginUserName"]

Password
css=div.group > input[name="LoginPassword"]
```

Generally, xPath locators are considered more fragile as compared to CSS locators. So, it will be good to go with CSS locators.

Comment: No...I got the same error - with driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="LoginUserName"]').send_keys('aaaaa')

Comment: key was using whole css selector. glad it works for you now :)

Answer (score 0):

You imported `WebDriverWait` and `expected_conditions` but you don't use them

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='LoginUserName']")).send_keys(username)
```

This will wait up to 10 seconds for the element to be visible.

Comment: I corrected my code - TestingWithArif answer was the good one. Thank you